# Modify rich text in GWT or smartGWT widget or area

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, richtext

I am trying to create an area with HTML text, a DIV equivalent in GWT or SmartGWT.

Initially some plain text is displayed. User can highlight text and with a press of a button have that text have a line through and turn red in color. Also user can click anywhere in the text and type in new text which would appear underlined and green.

I need to get caret position for each modification as well as newly typed text and so on.

Is there a widget in GWT or SmartGWT that can provide me with such functionality ? currently I have an all javascript solution using DIV and inserting SPANs on click, but I want to move away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo of a RichTextArea and RichTextToolbar widgets:

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText

[RichTextArea](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html) exposes a formatter that can do the things that you need. So if you already have the buttons, you can simply use the formatter to do the work when each button is clicked.

UPDATE:

For example, if you want to strikeout a selected text or change its color, it can be done very easily:

```
formatter.toggleStrikethrough();
formatter.setForeColor("#F00");
```

If you need to get the selected text, you can use something like this:

```
private static native String getSelection(Element elem) /*-{
    var txt = "";
    var range;
    var parentElement;
    var container;

if (elem.contentWindow.getSelection) {
        txt = elem.contentWindow.getSelection();
} else if (elem.contentWindow.document.getSelection) {
        txt = elem.contentWindow.document.getSelection();
} else if (elem.contentWindow.document.selection) {
        range = elem.contentWindow.document.selection.createRange();
        txt = range.text;
}
return "" + txt;
}-*/;
```

Comment: This is not exactly that I want. I need to be able to exact caret position and entered text when user performs actions. 

Spasibo za stol' bystryj otvet.

Comment: Is there a way for me to talk to you directly ? how is strike through applied to ONLY selected text ? Can't find examples.

Comment: This is just one of the methods that you call when you want to change formatting of a selected text - the same way it works in all RichText widgets. Look at the documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.Formatter.html Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already seen, but SmarGWT has also a [RichTextEditor](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/RichTextEditor.html). There is a demo in http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_richedit

I have never used it but there are some functions related to fonts.

The returned editor area is a Canvas but you can probably set your own component with a "caret position" support.